Exporting wix contact list as json file
I am trying to build my first Wix website, and I am trying to connect it to a different application that I am building. I am trying to get a list of all users on my website using a python request so that I can connect their information to my external app, but I can't find a way to export the contact list.
I was trying to create a backend .js function that I could then call in python, but I can't figure out the proper way to export the user information.
How can I access this list, or is there an easier way to do what I'm trying to do?
This is the code that I have as my backend function on wix. As far as I understand according to the wix API documentation this should return a list of all contacts, but instead it returns an empty list. Where am I going wrong?

maybe you show us the process of how you are approaching the problem, And what are the results you are able to get. and the expected results. This might help in understanding the problem better
